# issue with the "cooking" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

We currently have two questions tagged [bishul](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bishul) and two tagged [cooking](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooking). The "bishul" questions deal with cooking, *bishul*, the act of heating something to prepare it. [One of the "cooking" questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8085) does also, but [the other](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7896) deals not with cooking (*bishul*, heating something) but with cooking (cuisine). We need IMO to fix these. Suggestions on how to do so?

Comment: So we have, so far, two cohesive answers about what to do: use `cooking-bishul` for things that concern cooking (heating food) and nothing for things that don't, or use `food-preparation` (or `kitchen`) for things that concern cooking (heating food) and for things that don't. I suppose we can do whichever gets more upvotes, or something.

Comment: I see I'm a few months late, but was there a conclusion reached on this issue? It seems there are many more questions with those tags now. What is the accepted procedure?

Comment: @DoubleAA, there has not been a conclusion as of yet.

Comment: I think we should go with WAF's answer considering by my count, 90% of the cooking questions are about the melacha of bishul. Additionally we have a tag for tying-knots-kosheir as one tag.

Comment: @DoubleAA, fine by me; and then the tag wiki will say it's for any cooking questions, not just _m'leches bishul_. I'll _bl"n_ now call the attention of those who have participated in this question's discussion to these new comments before any implementation.

Comment: As somebody who recently asked a cooking-related question, it would not have occurred to me to look for bishul.  I'd try cooking first, then kitchen, then give up.  I don't think there are so many cooking-related questions that we need two tags.

Comment: @msh210 Is there more systematic way of doing this or should I just retag and detag all 20 questions in question? (I don't mind doing so, just curious to learn about built-in tag features.)

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'll _bl"n_ merge them if there's no objection here in a couple of days. Don't bother retagging.

Comment: All right, I've effected the solution in WAF's answer. Thanks, all, for your input.

Comment: @msh210 Do you mind clarifying the scope in the tag wiki as you mentioned in an earlier comment?

Comment: @DoubleAA I already did. *Edit:* Oh, I see, it hasn't shown up. Merging tags always engenders a bit of lag all around, I find.

Comment: @msh210 Oops didn't see it. My bad. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there should be one tag: cooking-bishul. The term *bishul* is simply a translation. I'm not only being literal and pedantic here. Questions that have only to do with cooking will have this tag. Questions that have to do with cooking and the *halachos* thereof will have the [halacha-jewish-law](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha-jewish-law) tag in addition. Anyone who tags with "cooking-bishul" a question that has only to do with *hilchos bishul* would then not be wrong, and there would be no ambiguity as to the exact scope of "cooking".

Comment: Maybe what we need is melechet-bishul.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, but see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8085.

Comment: WAF, @IsaacMoses, please see new comments on the question, above.

Comment: @msh210 One tag containing the superset of topics makes sense to me in this case, given the comments above.

Answer (score 3):

I think rename the "cooking" tag "cooking-bishul" and detag the question that doesn't concern *bishul*.

Answer (score 1):

I think the cooking tag is more inline with bishul. Instead, how about tagging the [Meat Thermometer question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7896/tevilas-keilim-for-a-meat-thermometer) with "kitchen"? It seems more specific and accurate.

Comment: Do you anticipate other questions' being tagged "kitchen"?

Comment: @msh210 Yes, for example: how to check for bugs in lettuce. [Burning the Challah portion](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2465/burning-the-challah-portion), and the like...

Comment: You're thinking of something more specific than the (existing) "food" tag, though?

Comment: @msh210 food is generally about food - i.e. stuff you eat. Kitchen is more about making food - i.e. food preparation

Comment: @yydl Shouldn't the food preparation tag be "cooking" then?

Comment: @WAF well is how to check lettuce for bugs necessarily cooking. I think that cooking is included in Food Preparation. The reason I picked "kitchen" was because I thought it was an accurate, one-worded tag that expressed all those ideas. But I suppose food-preparation would also suffice

Comment: yydl, please see new comments on the question, above.

Comment: If I were posting about checking lettuce I wouldn't think to look for kitchen.  I'd probably try food first, then maybe cooking.  And if we *also* have food and cooking tags, I'm stumped by what kitchen would mean.